# AFNetworking : upload image with other parameters

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

First of all, thank you for read this question.

I am developing app which is using JSON webservice. In the app, I need to call webservice with image (profile Image) with some parameters.
My JSON request should be same as following...

```
{
  "adduser": {
  "firstname": "testFirstName",
  "lastname": "testLastName",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "projectids" : "1"
  }
  }
```

there is other variable as `profileimage` for uploading image.

I have write following code.

```
    NSDictionary *dictParameter = @{@"adduser": @{@"firstname": firstName, @"lastname":lastName,@"email":email, @"projectids":@"1"}};
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:strURL parameters:dictParameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
            }];
 [op start];
```

Above code log following error.

```
Error: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: json in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/app/webroot/webservices/include.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
{"status":"failure","message":"Your Request is Empty"} ***** Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x8abe490 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

If i use following code than it work fine. But i am not able to upload image.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   [manager POST:strURL parameters:dictParameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Thanks

Comment: It would not be optimized cause it will make 2 calls to your server, but a temporary solution could be return the urladdress of the user avatar with your current code, and then use `UIImageView+AFNetworking` to download the image

Comment: What do *you* think what AFN is doing with the parameters? What is your server expecting? How exactly is AFN composing the parts when receiving a hierarchial parameter structure?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a part where you actually add the image data you want to send to the server.

```
NSDictionary *dictParameter = @{@"adduser": @{@"firstname": firstName, @"lastname":lastName,@"email":email, @"projectids":@"1"}};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:strURL parameters:dictParameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
[formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
        } 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
            } 
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
            }];

 [op start];
```

Check the AFNetworking docs about [posting a multi-part request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#post-multi-part-request).

Comment: This is correct and also an issue in the OPs code. But it doesn't explain the error. I suspect, there is a problem with the parameters. Usually, sending hierarchical structured parameters ( like the JSON) is not "standard". Thus, whatever AFN is doing with them, requires custom code on the server side.

Comment: I tried with adding [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"profileimage" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
still it give same error

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: may be you are right, but what will be the reason that it is working with other code (describe in question)

Comment: @Playcool In the case where it works, AFN uses a *different* HTTP message whose Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Apparently, with this content type the parameters will be encoded such that the server can decode it properly. Your original HTTP request uses `multipart/form-data` MIME type as the Content-Type, which requires a different representation of the parameters. Perhaps, I need to add an *elaborated explanation* in an answer?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thanks for your explanation. I told my webservice developer to make change into request parameter. Let me check, it will work or not. Thanks

Comment: @CouchDeveloper you are right, I guess the first error has to do with the server not being able to decode the message, and the cocoa error is probably NSJSONSerialization parsing error because the responseString is not JSON (in whole).

Comment: Exactly. ;)  And at @playcool, you need to figure out *how* your JSON structure should be wrapped into a multi part message. Usually, this is NOT possible. Well, yes NOT possible, because basically a multipart message consists of one or more "parts". And each part is basically a key/value pair, where the representation of the value is specified through a Content-Type. So, how would you make a hierarchical JSON Object a list of key/value pairs? That's what you need to figure out, play cool. ;)

Comment: You should also take a look at different parameter / response serialization options offered by AFNetworking here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#serialization

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I remove "adduser" from hierarchy, still get same error.

Comment: Having a JSON like `{
  "firstname": "testFirstName",
  "lastname": "testLastName",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "projectids" : "1"
  }` MAY have worked, since AFN can interpret this as a list of key value pairs and each of them being strings. Do you have this JSON?

Comment: You need to figure out *what AFN* is doing with your parameters, and you need to know *what your server* is expecting. I'm assuming your server will expect each parameter (key/value pair) in *one* separate part, whose Content-Type is `text/plain; charset=utf-8`, but this kind of multipart message may not be composed by AFN. You need to check what AFN is actually doing and match that with that what your server is expecting.

Comment: finally, I separate two different web-services, one for image upload and another for add user detail. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following code with **ASIFormDataRequest** library.

```
-(IBAction)postPhotoButtonClickedButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [textViewStatusBox resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"postPhotoButtonClicked");
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *randomPictureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [self generateRandomString]] ;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage);
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webber.im/iphone/post_library.php"]];
    [request setPostValue:@"ASv48umPgx0tyuu9PnjxcQ" forKey:@"key"];
    [request addData:imageData withFileName:randomPictureName andContentType:@"multipart/form-data" forKey:@"picture"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
     }
    }
```

Here I have two parameters **key** and **picture**. You can modify it with your own parameters.
Hope it would help you a lot.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that JSON+formdata (image) is not working with AFNetworking.
So, I separate one task into two,
1) upload image using AFNetworking `formData appendPartWithFileURL` function
2) After uploading image successfully, get image name from server response.  Call add user web-service with that image name.

It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableDictionary *dicData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

```
[dicData setObject:placeName forKey:@"name"];

[dicData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude] forKey:@"latitude"];

[dicData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude] forKey:@"longitude"];

[dicData setObject: [NSNumber numberWithLong:categoryId] forKey:@"categoryId"];

[dicData setObject:@"1" forKey:@"userId"];

number=arc4random();
NSLog(@"Random Number=%d",number);

str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:insertPlaceData parameters:dicData constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:@"image" fileName:[str stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     //   NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);

        MainScreen *mainScreen=[[MainScreen alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainScreen animated:YES];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      //  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving data"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

    }];
```